# Should you use skeleton loading when you can't promise content?

Tags: usability, loading, lazy-loading

For example, we have a search where users will be searching from a finite amount of content that they have generated. If they search for something too specific and get 0 results there would be no content displayed.
Is it problematic to show skeletons of content if it's possible that they get zero results and the skeletons just disappear?

Answer (score 2):

If it takes more than one second for the system to return an answer to a user, even if the answer is "No results found", you should display some kind of [progress indicator](https://uxmovement.com/navigation/progress-bars-vs-spinners-when-to-use-which/). A skeleton screen is considered an [alternative to an indeterminate loading indicator](https://uxdesign.cc/what-you-should-know-about-skeleton-screens-a820c45a571a) (like a spinning wheel animation), vs. an alternative to the content that is being loaded (though it gives the user more information on what to expect.)

Consistency is best in this case - users should always see the same indicator when the system is performing the same task. Thus, you don't have to worry about a skeleton screen "duping" a user into believing that results have been found. Rather, like a spinning wheel, it is telling the user that information is still being retrieved. The indicator belongs to the loading task, rather than the results.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a hard rule for this so I would offer my judgment.
People like seeing work is being in process and seeing more complex things gives the feel of greater work being done.
For example, there was a study on some travel website loading screens. Surprisingly, people evaluated the version with several messages telling what database is being checked (which took more time than a simple loader) as doing a better search.
Not the certainty but I would advocate for more complex skeletons. Not the fire but nice to see the progress :)